# Networkdays and IFERROR

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

Here is an excel formula to calculate number of workdays between two dates:

**=IFERROR( IF ( A2 = B2, 0, NETWORKDAYS( A2, B2 ) -1 ), "" )**

is it possibe to write this formula in **SharePoint List as a calculated column** please?

Thanks

Comment: What if I want to exclude only Friday from the date please?

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, the **NETWORKDAYS** function can be used in excel, but not for SharePoint.

**Please following steps:**

1.Create two "**Date and Time**" column named StartDate and EndDate in list.

[image]

2.Then, create one "**Calculated**" column named Workdays

3.Please use the below Formula:

```
IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF([StartDate],[EndDate],”d”)),””,(DATEDIF([StartDate],[EndDate],”d”))+1-INT(DATEDIF([StartDate],[EndDate],”d”)/7)*2-IF((WEEKDAY([EndDate])-WEEKDAY([StartDate]))<0,2,0)-IF(OR(AND(WEEKDAY([EndDate])=7,WEEKDAY([StartDate])=7),AND(WEEKDAY([EndDate])=1,WEEKDAY([StartDate])=1)),1,0)-IF(AND(WEEKDAY([StartDate])=1,(WEEKDAY([EndDate])-WEEKDAY([StartDate]))>0),1,0)-IF(AND(NOT(WEEKDAY([StartDate])=7),WEEKDAY([EndDate])=7),1,0))
```

[image]

4.When you enter date, SharePoint will automatically calculated  the number of working days between the two dates.

[image]